# gwt internationalization

Tags: gwt, internationalization

there are three (open) questions about the internationalization of GWT, I have:

1) Is it a (huge) performance issue, to use only "Messages" for constant and parameterized text (that's possible), where you would use both "Messages" and "Constants" usually?

2) Is there a way to specify the original text in the source code, whose translations can then be specified somewhere? (e.g. `Translate("Hello")` in the source code and than in a properties file for e.g. spanish: `Hello = ¡Hola!`)

3) Do you know any translation-tools, which generate the properties and interfaces for you?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) I am not aware of any performance issues with Messages vs Constants. Since all code ends up as fairly optimized JavaScript anyway, it would seem like a minimal issue to me.

2) You can use the `DefaultMessage` annotation:

```
@DefaultMessage("Hello")
String hello();
```

In this case, if no corresponding translation file is found, the default message is used.

3) [i18nCreator](http://code.google.com/docreader/#p=google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5&s=google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5&t=DevGuideI18nCreator)

Comment: thanks very much! for 3) do you know a GUI or something, where you just type in the translations, without handling the properties and interface files.

Comment: I have not yet heard of such a tool, could be nice though :)